# move draggable between droppable + sortable containers

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable, droppable

I've got a scenario where I have multiple `droppable` containers, that are also `sortable`. I need to be able to drag `clone`s from my source `draggable`, and drop them on any of the `droppables`. Within each `droppable`, the items need to be `sortable`. I also need to be able to drag a `draggable` from one `droppable` to another.

[**Here is a JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cz7e5/1/) I've started as a proof of concept that I can't quite get working.

There are two issues I can see:

1. If you drag two items onto the first (left-most) `droppable` container, and then drag the bottom one up to the top (to re-sort them), you'll notice an animation coming from the source `draggable` up top. I assume this has something to do with the clone but I wasn't able to find the culprit.
2. With the two items on the first (left-most) `droppable` container, if you try and drag one of the items over to the middle `droppable`, you see it revert again animate back from the source `draggable` up top.

I hope I'm not making it overly complex but in the `drop` function I'm using the `dropped` class to tell me whether the item has been dropped or not before, and if it doesn't have the class I know it's the first time dropping , hence creating the clone and appending it to the `droppable`.

Otherwise, if the `draggable` has been dropped (i.e. has the class `dropped`), and changed `droppables`, I won't re-clone it but append it to the new `droppable`.

```
if(ui.draggable.hasClass("dropped") && DifferentSource()){
   // this item was already dropped, just changed sources:
   ui.draggable.appendTo($(this));
} else if(ui.draggable.hasClass("dropped") == false) {
   var clone = ui.draggable.clone();
   count += 1;
   clone.html("item " + count);
   clone.addClass("dropped");
   clone.appendTo($(this));
}
```

Can anyone see what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The missing key was `sortable`'s `connectWith` property. This allowed me to connect the different `droppable`s so that `sortable` doesn't revert back when changing `droppable`s.

Here is the [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cz7e5/3/). Hopefully this saves someone time in the future!