# Drag out of a sortable

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

Site: http://ace.brianhare.com/test/

I want it so cards can be draggable to the bottom of the screen (Players hand). Right now this functionality works but once it is in the players hand it cannot be dragged out of the hand.

I want the cards to be able to be dragged onto the table and then be freely draggable. How do I get the cards to be dragged out of the hand and back to the table freely? It really glitches once a card is dragged to the hand it wont even move.

Comment: Does this help? I asked a similar question before about dragging between `sortable`s: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21639020/move-draggable-between-droppable-sortable-containers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got what I wanted finally:

```
$('*:not(:input)').disableSelection();

$(".sortable").sortable({
    connectWith: '.sortable, .droppable',
    beforeStop: function (event, ui) {
        ui.item.css('position', 'relative');
    }
});

$(".droppable").droppable({
    tolerance: "fit",
    drop: function (ev, ui) {

        if(ui.draggable.hasClass('ui-sortable-helper')) {
            var clone = ui.draggable.clone();
            ui.draggable.remove();
            $(this).append(clone);
            $(clone).draggable({
                connectToSortable: '.sortable'
            });
        }


    }
});


$('.draggable').draggable({
    connectToSortable: '.sortable'
});
```

DEMO:
http://jsfiddle.net/nfuza42k/

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this plugin (especially the demos). I think it will help you. http://rubaxa.github.io/Sortable/

Comment: This is a nice plugin but it kind of duplicates what Jquery UI can already do and I dont wan't to add an additional plugin when I have the resources already to do what I want (We use the UI for other things too).  And PS this is a standalone not a jQuery plugin.